# Oracle SOA 12c correcting and reprocessing data

Tags: oracle, soa, weblogic12c, osb, oracle-bam

We have a requirement where we need to correct the payload and reprocess the transaction from the point of failure.The data could be edited by some business owner based on some UI, for data issues or reprocessed by weblogic Admin for any technical issue.

The point of failure could be a BPEL composite or OSB in the defined scope for now.

We are using BAM in the current flow for reporting but I think such an approach is not possible in BAM.

The idea right now is to have milestones defined in the flows and persist data in some table along with payload in case of failures.Can someone help in pointing to some kind of approach we can take in the Fusion Middleware stack. We do not want to go the ADF or any Java related UI for now.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something you'd have to hand off to a human workflow task or something similar.  I don't have much experience with this, as our group doesn't take responsibility for someone else's data.  We tend to push this kind of issue off on the producer by kicking an error back or submitting some other kind of service call to their system to let these bad records queue up for them to work on using their own tools.

If the data you're getting in SOA is bad, and you want to fix it on the producer side, it's probably easier to find a way to let that client know that records A, B, C, D, etc., are bad and have them figure out how their system needs to be modified to change those specific records.  That way your system isn't responsible for all the added auditing, logging, tracing, etc., that comes with being responsible for the data.

That said, it sounds like it requires a lot of manual intervention, so I would just push it off to the human workflow engine, which is ideally suited for that kind of work:

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/servicecomps/servicecomps-developdeploy.htm

Comment: Thanks Nick,I will explore the human task and will see if I can edit the payload and resubmit the instance.This is a unique requirement which business wants for some flows.    Regards,Rahul